# Unknown host exception, Apache HttpClient, Java, wunderground

Tags: java, android, url, apache-httpclient-4.x, unknown-host

I've been stuck on this particular dilemma for some time, I have scoured the site and found some help, but not to my particular issue. I'm trying to connect to a website to extract JSON data from it. The host is what i'm not sure about:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("www.wunderground.com", 80);
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urllink); // urllink is "api.wunderground.com/api/my_key/conditions/forecast/hourly/alerts/q/32256.json"
    httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(targetHost, httpGet);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // print stacktrace
        return null;
    } finally {
        try {
            instream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // print stacktrace
            return null;
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
```

The host could either be `www.wunderground.com` or `api.wunderground.com`, but when I try either of them i get `Unknown host exception`.

**I found the error. It was that I did not have the permission in the android manifest!**

Comment: Can you send a ping request? Maybe something is wrong with you local installation.

Comment: hmm, that sounds like it could be something. I can access the website fine. but pinging it returns "timed out" indefenitely

Comment: your code works fine for me with a little addition: your **urllink** should begin with a protocol: **http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_Key/features/settings/q/query.format**. Also, I removed unnessecary targetHost and replaced **client.execute(targetHost, httpGet);** with just **client.execute(httpGet);**

Comment: I'm still getting unknown host. I guess that means I'm behind a firewall or proxy? solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call should be similar to:

http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_Key/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json

or as stated in the [API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/index),

```
GET http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_Key/features/settings/q/query.format
```

Comment: right, the urllink is that, sorry. I'll add that to the main post

Comment: So does it answer your question?

Comment: it does not, the issue is still "unknown host"

Comment: Did you try with this address: http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_Key/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json?

Comment: yep, still "unknown host exception"

Comment: Try access the exact address using a browser. It can tell you if you're wrong.